# How do you use Firebase Auth without a Web Token

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using a third party sdk to sign in users. However that sdk does not generate any token as such. It returns the mobile and user Name.

But I use Firebase for all my other requirements. Thus i need to add the users in the Auth system so i can securely use my realtime database and storage.

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens

I did go through this but this suggests adding logic to the authentication server, which I dont have access to so i cant make changes to incorporate a JWT.

Can someone please suggest a way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Generating custom tokens requires a server environment as sensitive private keys are involved in that process. Consider using an [HTTP endpoint](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) with Cloud Functions to do so.

Note the 3rd party SDK you are using must be able to produce the authentication assertion server side too, as you can't just send a username to that endpoint and mint a custom token from that. That can easily be abused.